# An explicit hard function for P/poly

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, interactive-proofs

[It is known](https://lance.fortnow.com/papers/files/nonrel.pdf) that $\textbf{MA}_{\textbf{EXP}} \not\subset \textbf{P/poly}$. Is it known any *explicit* language from $\textbf{MA}_{\textbf{EXP}}$ that does not belongs to $\textbf{P/poly}$?

(An example of explicit language is any **EXPSPACE**-complete language but presumably $\textbf{EXPSPACE} \not=\textbf{MA}_{\textbf{EXP}}$).